# Second level of sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a sidebar with a submenu that extends to the right instead of down. A rough picture below:[image]

I'm fairly new with flexbox and that is all I could come up with:

HTML:

```
    <div class="d-flex align-items-stretch">
      <nav class="side-navigation">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav d-flex flex-column">
          <li class="sidebar-nav-expand d-flex toggle">
            <a class="nav-link sidebar-nav-expand-toggle py-3" href="#">
              <span class="icon icon-ic_compute"></span>
              <span class="nav-item-text">Menu1</span>
              <span class="float-right"><i class="fas fa-mortar-pestle"></i></span>
            </a>
            <div class="sidebar-nav-expand-items">
              <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li class="sidebar-nav-item py-3">
                  <a class="nav-link py-1" href="#some-url1">
                    <span class="nav-item-text">Menu1 subitem1</span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li class="sidebar-nav-item py-3">
                  <a class="nav-link py-1" href="#some-url2">
                    <span class="nav-item-text">Menu1 subitem2</span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li class="sidebar-nav-item py-3">
                  <a class="nav-link py-1" href="#some-url3">
                    <span class="nav-item-text">Menu1 subitem3</span>
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="sidebar-nav-expand d-flex">
            <a class="nav-link sidebar-nav-expand-toggle py-3" href="#">
              <span class="icon icon-ic_management"></span>
              <span class="nav-item-text">Menu2</span>
              <span class="float-right"><i class="fas fa-mortar-pestle"></i></span>
            </a>
            <div class="sidebar-nav-expand-items">
              <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li class="sidebar-nav-item py-3">
                  <a class="nav-link py-1" href="#some-url21">
                    <span class="nav-item-text">Menu2 subitem1</span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li class="sidebar-nav-item py-3">
                  <a class="nav-link py-1" href="#some-url22">
                    <span class="nav-item-text">Menu2 subitem2</span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li class="sidebar-nav-item py-3">
                  <a class="nav-link py-1" href="#some-url23">
                    <span class="nav-item-text">Menu2 subitem3</span>
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="sidebar-nav-expand">
            <a class="nav-link py-3" href="#some-url">
              <span class="icon icon-ic_administration"></span>
              <span class="nav-item-text">Direct link</span>
              <span class="float-right"><i class="fas fa-mortar-pestle"></i></span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div class="main">
        Content
      </div>
    </div>
```

SCSS:

```
$white: #fff;
$whitesmoke: #ECEFF1;
$aliceblue: #f1f6ff;
$light-gray: #D6DADC;
$blue: #2971FB;
$light-blue: #BFD5FE;
$black: #263238;
$light-black: #364046;
$orange: #FF8F00;

.side-navigation {
  max-width: 540px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.sidebar-nav {
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  list-style: none;

  .nav-link {
    display: block;
    padding: .75rem 1rem;
    color: $white;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: 0 0;

    &:hover {
      color: $orange;
    }
  }

  .sidebar-nav-item {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .sidebar-nav-expand {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: $black;

    &.toggle {
      .sidebar-nav-expand-toggle {
        color: $orange;
      }
      .sidebar-nav-expand-items {
        margin-left: 0;
      }
    }

    .sidebar-nav-expand-toggle {
      width: 270px;
      z-index: 2;
    }

    .sidebar-nav-expand-items {
      width: 270px;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: $light-gray;
      transition: margin-left .25s ease-in-out;
      margin-left: -270px;
      color: $black;

      .nav-link {
        color: $black;

        &:hover {
          color: $orange;
        }

        &:not(.active) {
          margin-left: 8px;
        }
        &.active {
          border-left: solid 8px $orange;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

JS:

```
    $('.sidebar-nav-expand-toggle').on('click', function() {
        let self = $(this);
        self.parent('.sidebar-nav-expand').toggleClass('toggle');
        $('.main').toggleClass('toggle');
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cj4375er/

As you can see the child is not properly hidden under the parent and submenus are stacked, if a menu is opened I want all other menus to close. Also, there is too much space between menu items.
I would just need some points in the right direction. If there is an example of a similar case I would be happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you tried to *cover* the submenu bar using `z-index: 2` at that `sidebar-nav-expand-toggle`. However, your items are not properly hidden because your `sidebar-nav-expand-toggle` has no background (i.e. it's transparent). The background is actually from `sidebar-nav-expand` (`#263238`) that bleeds through the `sidebar-nav-expand-toggle` because `sidebar-nav-expand-toggle` is transparent. Therefore, the solution is to instruct the `sidebar-nav-expand-toggle` to inherit the same background as its parent, resulting in this code below:

```
.sidebar-nav-expand-toggle {
  width: 270px;
  z-index: 2;
  background: inherit;
}
```

Your menus are stacked because you did not handle the closing of the other submenus that may be open (you merely toggled the one that is clicked, but you didn't close the ones that may be open that are not clicked). A simple addition to your JS code fixes this:

```
$('.sidebar-nav-expand-toggle').on('click', function() {
  let self = $(this);
  let toggled = self.parent('.sidebar-nav-expand').hasClass('toggle')

  hideAllSubmenu()

  if (toggled) 
    self.parent('.sidebar-nav-expand').removeClass('toggle')
  else 
    self.parent('.sidebar-nav-expand').addClass('toggle')

  $('.main').toggleClass('toggle');
});

function hideAllSubmenu() {
  let submenus = $('.sidebar-nav-expand-toggle')
  submenus.parent('.sidebar-nav-expand').removeClass('toggle')
}
```

*There is too much space between menu items*. My suggestion would be to make a flexbox that has only the three menu items with padding. And then, for each of those menus (can be `a` or `div`), create a `div` inside it that has `position: absolute` based on those menus. You can then slide it out when clicked by using `transform: translate`. That way, the height is not dependent on a wrapping container's height.

Also, I see that you are using SCSS. I really suggest reading about [BEM selectors here](https://css-tricks.com/bem-101/) to better utilize SCSS to create a more easily readable code.

**EDIT:**

I've added a little working example of what I meant by using `position: absolute` and still being able to push the main content to the right when the submenu expands. Take a look below (please adjust this minimal working example to what you need):

```js
function resetSubmenuStyles() {
  let submenus = document.querySelectorAll('.submenu div')
  for (let submenu of submenus) {
    submenu.style.width = ''
    submenu.style.visibility = ''
  }
}

document.querySelector('#menuOne').addEventListener('click', e => {
  let submenu = document.querySelector('.submenu')
  let submenuOne = document.querySelector('#submenuOne')
  let submenuStyle = window.getComputedStyle(submenuOne)
  let submenuWidth = parseInt(submenuStyle.getPropertyValue('width')) - parseInt(submenuStyle.getPropertyValue('padding-left')) - parseInt(submenuStyle.getPropertyValue('padding-right'))
  
  resetSubmenuStyles()
  if (submenuWidth == 0) {
    submenu.style.width = '20%'
    submenuOne.style.width = '100%'
    submenuOne.style.visibility = 'visible'
  }
  else {
    submenu.style.width = ''
    submenuOne.style.width = ''
    submenuOne.style.visibility = ''
  }
})

document.querySelector('#menuTwo').addEventListener('click', e => {
  let submenu = document.querySelector('.submenu')
  let submenuTwo = document.querySelector('#submenuTwo')
  let submenuStyle = window.getComputedStyle(submenuTwo)
  let submenuWidth = parseInt(submenuStyle.getPropertyValue('width')) - parseInt(submenuStyle.getPropertyValue('padding-left')) - parseInt(submenuStyle.getPropertyValue('padding-right'))
  resetSubmenuStyles()
  if (submenuWidth == 0) {
    submenu.style.width = '20%'
    submenuTwo.style.width = '100%'
    submenuTwo.style.visibility = 'visible'
  }
  else {
    submenu.style.width = ''
    submenuTwo.style.width = ''
    submenuTwo.style.visibility = ''
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

html, body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
}

.menu {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  color: #FFF;
}

.menu h1 {
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.submenu {
  position: relative;
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #333;
  color: #FFF;
}

.submenu div {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "menu">
  <h1 id = "menuOne">Test</h1>
  <h1 id = "menuTwo">Test</h1>
</div>

<div class = "submenu">
  <div id = "submenuOne">
    Submenu Test One
  </div>
  
  <div id = "submenuTwo">
    Submenu Test Two
  </div>
</div>

<div id = "main">Some Content</div>
```

Comment: I want second menu to extend and also push the main content to the right, so I can't really work with absolute positioning. Also, I would like the second manu to take full height and elements positioned always at the top. I don't know if flex is the right approach here.

Comment: @BlakeGibbs Although it is implied in your picture that you want those requirements, I say that adding an explicit explanation would help others in fully understanding what you exactly need. So perhaps add those descriptions to the original question ;-)

Comment: @BlakeGibbs There you go. I've added details on how to use `position: absolute` to get what you want. Note that it is a minimal working example, code simplification and edge-case precaution should still be considered yourself.